# How to maintain case and ignore spaces in Vigenere Cipher

Tags: javascript, encryption

I need to be able to keep the same case, i.e. "Attack" will be "Lxfopv", with the key "lemon". In addition, I need to keep any spaces within the message to be encrypted.

I used an if statement to check for whitespace

```
    if(text.charAt(i) == ' '){
      continue;
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
function encrypt(text, key) {
  var output= '';
  var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    var a= alphabet.indexOf(key.charAt(i % key.length));
    var b= alphabet.indexOf(text.charAt(i));
    if(text.charAt(i) == ' '){
      continue;
    }else{
      output += alphabet.charAt((a+ b) % alphabet.length);

    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

if pass in "Attack at Dawn", my desired output should be `Lxfopv ef Rnhr` but I am recieving `LxFopvmHOeIB` with the key "lemon".

How can I fix this to get the desired output? Is it something to do with the fact that I have hardcoded my alphabet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep the case, you will have to work your transformation on a single case.
Only at the time of adding it to your output, will you convert it to the correct case.

And in order to get the same value than other algorithms which do ignore the space character, you have to use a second iterator variable. 
This iterator should get incremented only on valid inputs, and will be used to iterate the `key`.

```js
inp.oninput = e => log.textContent = encrypt(inp.value, 'lemon');

function encrypt(text, key) {
  var output= '';
  // single case dictionary
  var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var low = text.toLowerCase(); // we'll work on this one

  for(let i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    // here we use `j` for the key
    let a = alphabet.indexOf(key.charAt(j % key.length));
    let b = alphabet.indexOf(low.charAt(i));
    let out = ''; // the character we'll add
    if(low.charAt(i) == ' '){
      out = ' '; // keep spaces untouched
    }else if(b > -1){ // only if valid
      out = alphabet.charAt((a+ b) % alphabet.length); // get the ciphered value
      j++; // only here we increment `j`
    }
    if(low[i] !== text[i]) { // if input and lower case are different
      // that means that input was upper case
      out = out.toUpperCase();
    }
    output += out; 
  }
  return output;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp"> <pre id="log"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the space to your alphabet:

```
if(text.charAt(i) == ' '){
  output += " ";
}
```